# AsyncTask as Inner class and static field issue

Tags: android, static, android-asynctask, inner-classes

I have a method `searchPlace()` that updates a `static Arrays` of custom Place Object in a class A (FindItOnMap) with a google map, and a method `updateMap()` that updates the various geopoints .
I invoke these methods `Button.onClick` and all works properly.

Since these methods use internet data this operation could take a while, I have been looking for the implementation of an inner class B(`YourCustomAsyncTask`) inside the class A that extends `AsyncTask` to show a waiting dialog during the processing of these two methods

An user suggested a solution in this form (that apparently seems valid):

```
public class FindItOnMap extends MapActivity { 
    static Place[] foundResults; 
    private ProgressDialog dialog; 

    @Override 
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { 
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
        setContentView(R.layout.ricerca_condominio); 
        mapView = (MapView)findViewById(R.id.mapView); 
             ........... 

        ((ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btSearch)).setOnClickListener(mSearchListenerListener); 
    } 

    OnClickListener mSearchListener = new OnClickListener() { 
        public void onClick(View v) { 
            String location=editorLocation.getText().toString(); 
            String name=editorName.getText().toString(); 
            //Call the AsyncTask here 
            new YourCustomAsyncTask().execute(new String[] {name, location}); 
        }
    }; 


    private class YourCustomAsyncTask extends AsyncTask <String, Void, Void> {  
        @Override  
        protected void onPreExecute() {  
            dialog = new ProgressDialog(Main.this);  
            dialog.setMessage("Loading....");  
            dialog.setIndeterminate(true);  
            dialog.setCancelable(true);  
            dialog.show(); //Maybe you should call it in ruinOnUIThread in doInBackGround as suggested from a previous answer 
        }  

        @Override  
        protected Void doInBackground(String... strings) {  
            try {  
                search(strings[0], string[1]);  
                return null;
            } catch(Exception e) { 
            } 
        } 

        @Override  
        protected void onPostExecute(Void params) {  
            updateMapWithResult();  
            dialog.dismiss();  
            //result  
        }  
..... 
    }
```

The waiting dialog is showed and the methods are invoked in background,
However for some strange reason the static list `foundResults` results filled with various `null` items...

How is this possible?

If I invoke the method search(location, name) outside the inner class all works properly and `updateMapWithResult();` updates all geopoint, so these two methods are ok.  Only if I try to invoke this in the inner class the json calls seem to be working but the static variable `foundResults` is filled with `null` elements and the program doesn't work properly.

Any suggestion?

Comment: Is there a specific reason that `foundResults` is `static`? Your inner class should be able to access it without it being `static`... Not sure if that will solve your problem but worth a test.

Comment: yes, is static because is used in various others static procedures inside the class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have understand where is the problem. 
You have to run the search method on the UI thread.

So change this code block:

```
  @Override  
        protected Void doInBackground(String... strings) {  
           try {  

              search(strings[0], string[1]);  
              return null;

           } catch(Exception e) { 
           } 

        }
```

with this

```
 @Override  
        protected Void doInBackground(final String... strings) {  
           try {  
              runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
               public void run() {
                     search(strings[0], string[1]);  
                     return null;
                   }
              });

           } catch(Exception e) { 
                 e.printStackTrace();
           } 
        }
```

And all should works correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one problem:

```
OnClickListener mSearchListener = new OnClickListener() { 
        public void onClick(View v) { 
                String Location=editorLocation.getText().toString(); 
                String name=editorName.getText().toString(); 
             //Call the AsyncTask here 
            new YourCustomAsyncTask().execute(new String[] {name, location}); 

        }
```

Your `Location` should be `location`.

Also here:

```
@Override  
        protected Void doInBackground(String... strings) {  
           try {  

              search(strings[0], string[1]);  

           } catch(Exception e) { 
           } 

        } 

    @Override  
    protected void onPostExecute(Void params) {  
        updateMapWithResult();  
        dialog.dismiss();  
        //result  

    }
```

In `doInBackground` you don't assign a value after you search. You might try this:

```
@Override  
        protected Void doInBackground(String... strings) {  
           try {  

              search(strings[0], string[1]);  
              String name = string[0];
              String location = string[1]

           } catch(Exception e) { 
           } 

        }
```

Or something else that will assign value while it runs. As it is, it appears that you just search, and then nothing else.

The reason `foundResults` is `null` is because you don't ever assign it a value.

Comment: Location is a trascription error, was location in my program,
search is a void static method that updates the static fields of the class with a value so... Why I must esplicit the values assignment? How I could do this?

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with your `AsyncTask`. Please include the `search()` method.

Comment: the search method is a static method that updates the static fields of the class with a value and in the outer class works fine... the problem is that when is invoked in the inner class the static fields of the outer class aren't updated correctly... so I think that isn't important how is implemented search